# Better jQuery function argument with if-statement?

Tags: javascript

```
function check_itv(key) {

if (key.length){

    if(key=="left"){
        left_itv = setInterval(left,100);
        check_left= false;
        check_right=true;
        check_up=true;
        check_down=true;
        clearInterval(right_itv);
        clearInterval(down_itv);
        clearInterval(up_itv);
    }

    if(key=="right"){
        right_itv = setInterval(right,100);
        check_left= true;
        check_right=false;
        check_up=true;
        check_down=true;
        clearInterval(left_itv);
        clearInterval(down_itv);
        clearInterval(up_itv);
    }

    if(key=="up"){
        up_itv = setInterval(up,100);
        check_left= true;
        check_right=true;
        check_up=false;
        check_down=true;
        clearInterval(left_itv);
        clearInterval(right_itv);
        clearInterval(down_itv);
    }

    if(key=="down"){
        down_itv = setInterval(down,100);
        check_left= true;
        check_right=true;
        check_up=true;
        check_down=false;
        clearInterval(left_itv);
        clearInterval(right_itv);
        clearInterval(up_itv);
    }

}

}

check_left = true;
check_right = true;
check_up = true;
check_down = true;
left_itv = "";
right_itv = "";
up_itv = "";
down_itv = "";
```

Try to do shorter and better, Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Comment: Don't have all of these intervals... have one, and set a variable for the direction.

Comment: i know about global & local , thanks @rlemon

Comment: @l2aelba What do you mean with "better"? (Faster? Easier to maintain? More compliant with standards? Working in <old browser>?) **What are you trying to accomplish?** Why are you not using var: `var check_left = true;`? Why do you have variables and methods in multiples of 4 and not a single variable for the direction? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing too much, here are some tips on improving your code.

Assumptions:

- You're working in modern web browser.
- left, up, down, right are defined else where.

## 1)

Define all the variables at the top. I'm not sure where the fucntions left, up, down, right are.

## 2)

Use a switch instead of multiple if else.

## 3)

Perform an operation to collection if multiple elements share the same functionality. Refer to `resetValues()`

## 4)

Try to make all the if conditions as small as possible. Refer to `!key.length`

Here's what I came up with.

```
Array.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach || function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
        fn.call(scope || this, this[i], i, this);
    }
};

var self = this,
    check_left, check_right, check_up, check_down,
    left_itv, right_itv, up_itv, down_itv;
    
var resetValues = function(){
    ["left_itv", "right_itv", "up_itv", "down_itv"].forEach(function(el){
        clearInterval( self[el] );
    });
    ["check_left", "check_right", "check_up", "check_down"].forEach(function(el){
        self[el] = true;
    });
};

resetValues();

function check_itv(key) {
    if (!key.length) {
        return;
    }
    resetValues();
    switch( key ){
        case "left":
            left_itv = setInterval(left, 100);
            check_left = false;
            break;
        case "right":
            right_itv = setInterval(right, 100);
            check_right = false;
            break;
        case "up":
            up_itv = setInterval(up, 100);
            check_up = false;
            break;
        case "down":
            down_itv = setInterval(down, 100);
            check_down = false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could swap the global variables inside a singleton(namespace) that has a reset functions. But that add a bit of complexity.

Comment: Nice, but use have to use :
var check_left = true;
var check_right = true;
var check_up = true;
var check_down = true;

so thats work ! :D

Comment: @l2aelba Updated the code, so that `resetValues()` set the check direction values when the script loads. Thanks for the update.